# PHP prepared statement with mysql multiple selection doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

the below php code doesn't return anything while the below one returns value, the only difference is the multiple selection. why is that?
(When I test is in my browser it dosen't shot anything)
I also tried to put the selection between () but doesn't help.

NON Working code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("x", "w", "y", "z");
$coresite = "Abbasya";
$rowx = "103";
$columnx = "3";
$directionx = "Back";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CABOwner, EtisaatTeam FROM CAB WHERE (SiteName=? AND Row=? AND Col=? AND Direction=?)"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $coresite, $rowx, $columnx, $directionx);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($cabinet);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        echo json_encode($cabinet).",";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else{
    $mysqli->close();    
}
```

?>

Working Code with one selection:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("x", "w", "y", "z");
$coresite = "Abbasya";
$rowx = "103";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Col FROM CAB WHERE (SiteName=? AND Row=?)"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $coresite, $rowx);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Col);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        echo json_encode($Col).",";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else{
    $mysqli->close();    
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"only difference is the multiple selection"_; the queries select different fields using different conditions; the first query's conditions being possibly much narrower. (If you are expecting the first to be more inclusive, perhaps you mean `OR`?)

Comment: I mean in the non working code I am selecting two items which are CABOwner, EtisaatTeam while in the working one I select only one item which is Col. why the first one isn't working? I tried also to add them between () to be (CABOwner, EtisaatTeam) but didn't work. and I mean and condition not or. is the selection statement is right?

Comment: Please take some time to format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it returns multiple values you need to bind to multiple variables. Like `$stmt->bind_result($Col1, $Col2);`

Comment: Great. This works :)